# Wampserver red or orange icon issues?

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver

I've installed wampserver 2.5 on my PC (windows 10) and i am facing red/orange icon issues but when i hover my cursor it shows wamp is running. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persist, you can open the file of "httpd.conf" and confirm the format. Sometimes during the install process occurs this kind of issues. But is possible solve the issue with the next modifications.

Remember in my case im using the port "8383" isntead "80"

```
    1.- Open the file "httpd.conf" and copy all the text.
    2.- Open a note++ and paste the text. (The reason of this action is just to have the correct format. )
    3.- Check the line 61 you have only the next text "#Listen 12.34.56.78:8383"
    4.- Line 62 with the next text "Listen 0.0.0.0:8383"
    5.- Finally the line 63 with the text "Listen [::0]:8383" (in the link you will see the expected result)
    6.- Copy and paste the text into "httpd.conf"
    7.- Save the changes
    8.- Restart the services
```

[you will have something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoYJB.png)

After restart the services, you will see all the services Working fine and the Wamp server as "Online" status.

Please let me know if this work for you. I saw this incident on a Windows 10 and didnt happened before with a Windows 7 or less.

Answer (score -1):

***Step 1:***
**Resolving Port 80 Issue**

1. Left click on wampserver icon then ***Apache>>Service>>Test Port 80***.(This will show you which program in your system using port 80).
2. If port 80 used by "***Microsoft IIS***" then simply run "***Command Prompt***" as ***Admin*** and type this command ***net stop was /y***.
3. If port 80 used by ***Skype*** then go to ***Tools>>Options>>Advanced>>Connections*** and "***Uncheck***" the box "***use port 80 and 443 as alternative***"

**Step 2: Check Port 80 Availability**

4. Restart all services by left clicking on wampserver icon and select ***Restart All Services***
   ***Problem is still there???***
5. Check the Apache service started or not by clicking ***Apache>>Service***. If the service has started then you it means Apache is using port 80.
6. Check MySql service by left clicking on wampserver icon and then go to ***MySql>>Service***. If service isn't started then open ***my.ini*** file. For this left click on wampserver icon and then go to ***MySql*** and click on ***my.ini*** and it will open with notepad.
7. Press ***Ctrl+F*** and type ***3306*** and replace them all founded items with ***3307***.
8. Restart all services by left clicking on wampserver icon and select ***Restart All Services***

**Hurryyyy....That it....**
***Enjoy with Wampserver***

Comment: Add link where you find this info.

Comment: `net stop was /y` is not a permanent solution. IIS will start again on the next reboot. If you are not using IIS uninstall it, or at least disable it. There are also other bit that come with IIS that will use port 80.

Comment: It is very ODD that port 3306 is being used by something else, **unless you have 2 MYSQL Servers running** on this machine. Until you become an expert I would uninstall the other MYSQL Server, after ensuring it is not required and backing up any databases it may contain

Comment: If you do change MYSQL to use a different port you will also need to amend the `php.ini` file and change this parameter to match the new port number `mysqli.default_port =`

Comment: @Katana! this answer is the result of lot of google search

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i have two MySql installed and your other comments are very useful and helpful for me. Microsoft IIS is using again port 80. You are right.

Comment: Is there a reason for 2 MYSQL Server instances. One should be enough for anybody.

Comment: no actually. I can say that was just for mistake :P